# Implementing multiple dialogs with similar processing

Tags: user-interface, mfc

We have multiple dialogs in our MFC program that are very similar.  Each one of these dialogs contain similar controls (i.e., they all contain a name, date, address, etc).  Because of this, we've had to code out the display code multiple times for the windows despite the fact that the processing of these controls is identical.  I'm looking for suggestions on how to change up our guis so that i have to only do the processing at one spot and not have to do it multiple times.
My thought was to have a class that would do the processing and pass pointers to the controls to display to that class, though i feel that is not a very good OO design.

Thoughts?

Comment: Your solution sounds OK to me. Another possibility would be to make only **one** dialog and tweak it according to the different situations.

Comment: I had considered that, but there is enough different between the dialogs that ultimately it would have been more effort to manage them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a base class derived from `CDialog` (say `CMyDlgBase`), place all your common functions there and derive your dialog classes from `CMyDlgBase` instead of `CDialog`.

You can now call the functions in `CMyDlgBase` as if they were declared directly in your dialog classes.

**EDIT** sample code to validate an item common to dialogs (`CDlg1` and `CDlg2` are derived from `CMyDlgBase`), error checking code not included:

```
BOOL CMyDlgBase::ValidateName(UINT nID)
{   CString ss;
    CEdit *pEdit = GetDlgItem(nID);
    pEdit->GetWindowText(ss);
    if (ss.Find(_T("A")) < 0) // some kind of validation
    {   MessageBox(_T("Name should contain the character 'A'"));
        pEdit->SetFocus();
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

---

```
CDlg1::OnOK()
{    if (!ValidateName(IDC_DLG1_NAME)) // resource id value = 101
         return;
     CDialog::OnOK(); // This will close the dialog and DoModal will return.
}

CDlg2::OnOK()
{    if (!ValidateName(IDC_DLG2_NAME)) // resource id value = 102
         return;
     CDialog::OnOK(); // This will close the dialog and DoModal will return.
}
```

Comment: In this scenario how do I handle access to the controls? Would I create all the common controls in the base class?

Comment: No, you would create the controls in each dialog class, the base class has access to the controls either via the resourceID or via the pointer to the control.

Comment: Is this solution dependent on the common controls having the same resource ids across the dialogs? If not, can you give me an example of how you envision it being used?

Comment: No, the resource IDs can be different, it is as if the base class functions were copied into each class -- edited the answer to include sample code to validate an item common to dialogs.

Comment: Okay, i follow what you did there.  I didn't think there was a way to get around a parameter list.  If i am grabbing data from/populating multiple controls, then each one that i am accessing in the base class will have to be a parameter passed in.  Do you feel a pointer to the control will simplify the code a bit more?

Comment: I decided to create setters for the controls in the base class. Now I don't have to pass parameters.